# Some Kivy Buildozer related stuff I'm not sure about

Tags: android, installation, kivy, buildozer

My Setup:
VM VirtualBox on windows 7 home p.
Guest - Linux Ubuntu 14.04

I have installed buildozer and dependencies and can run buildozer android debug and get an apk in the bin folder of the root project directory.

I have some questions that are killing me.

- Why is it when I call buildozer android release, no apk gets placed in the bin folder in the project root directory.  Instead I find the release apk in .buildozer......dist/mygame/release.unsigned-apk?  Is it suppose to be there?
- I can use keytool to create a .keystore file and run jarsinger...  but, I don't have DIR ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/build-tools/22.0.1/zipalign -v 4.  If buildozer downloaded the android sdk and ndk, should I have zipalign somewhere?  How can I build a debug apk if I didn't have the sdk and ndk?  So how come I don't see an sdk or ndk folder anywhere on my system?
- In my spec file, I use requirements kivy=master.  Is that ok?

PS, I know the sdk and ndk were downloaded because it took forever to get those but where are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release apk doesn't go to the bin folder in root, but by default goes to the  bin folder in distrb directory, which is in the hidden .buildozer path (in the root project folder).  Only the debug release goes to the bin folder that gets created in the project root.

The NDK and SDK were found in the hidden .buildozer path located in my Home directory.  Linux Ubuntu is one system that would be superior in the game "hide-n-seek"...if it were human.....   Which might happen given the way mankind constant feed human life and soul into machines.  :D